# How to check if user is in a google group using service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-groups

I have a service that needs to check if a specific gmail (g-suite) account belongs to a google group.

I've tried [Listing memberships of a Google Group](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/memberships-google-groups) but I have an error:

```
Error(2028): Permission denied for resource ... (or it may not exist).". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo', 'resourceType': 'cloudidentity.googleapis.com/Group', 'resourceName': '...', 'owner': 'domain:cloudidentity.googleapis.com', 'description': 'Error(2028): Permission denied for resource ... (or it may not exist).'}]
```

The code is the same as in the example.

The group belongs to the same org.

Comment: The service account need to be authorized to access to Workspace API, in the google Admin console.

Comment: By any chance are you using Terraform in your use-case? I have found one issue on github [1] where similar issues have been discussed. I hope that thread helps you!

[1]https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/8483

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to check whether a specific user in a google group is using a service account.

To check this we have an IAM policy analyzer, In which you can see a list of all groups/users/SAs who have a given permission on a resource.

Below are some highlights

- You need [certain permissions](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/analyzing-iam-policy#required-permissions) on organization to start.
- You need a custom role, get permission and group membership permissions to see
  full results.

For further reading please follow the [document](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/analyzing-iam-policy)